# unknown service ID Error when trying to deregister consul service

Tags: consul

I believe I should be able to use the consul tool or rest API to deregister a service, however, I always get an error:

```
$ consul catalog services
consul
shop
smtp

$ consul services deregister -id=smtp
Error deregistering service "": Unexpected response code: 404 (Unknown service ID "smtp". Ensure that the service ID is passed, not the service name.)

$ curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/agent/service/deregister/smtp
Unknown service ID "smtp". Ensure that the service ID is passed, not the service name.
```

I've looked at relevant examples and tried different APIs. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.hashicorp.com/consul/commands/services/deregister#consul-agent-service-deregistration

> The services deregister command deregisters a service with the local
> agent. Note that this command can only deregister services that were
> registered with the agent specified and is intended to be paired with
> services register. By default, the command deregisters services on the
> local agent.

Did you register the service on your local agent?